# How do i build a fiat payment processor(Gateway) on stellar

Tags: stellar-core, stellar-sdk, payments

I want to develop a payment gateway that can be integrated into online stores, merchants can seamlessly receive payments directly to their bank account. I want to build all the features on stellar. How would the stellar protocol play a role ???

Comment: This seems remarkably broad.  Could you narrow your question down a bit?

Comment: Sorry, how can i use stellar to build a payment gateway. Where do i start from ? something similar to stripe or paystack.

Comment: The "[stellarpay.io](https://stellarpay.io/documentation/custom/)" might help you.